# How to copy ('transplant') the value of one bit given by a single mask to a word?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Copying a value of a single bit is easy, it's just clearing and then setting it:

```
int copy(int from, int offset, int to) {
    int mask = 1 << 31-offset;
    return to & ~mask | from & mask;
}
```

Is it possible however to do this rather efficiently with the following signature?

```
/* to - a word to set the bit on
 * mask - mask specifying the bit to set/clear and the value of that bit:
 *        - if mask contains exactly one set bit, set that bit on 'to';
 *        - if mask contains exactly one zero, clear that bit on 'to';   
 */
int copy_bit(int mask, int to);
```

This is not purely academic (and in particular not a home assignment ;).
I am motivated by syntactic reasons and implementing it as a binary operator.
I came up with this:

```
int copy_bit(int mask, int to) {
    int lowestZero = ~mask & (mask+1);
    //overflow 'clear' masks to zero highest bit; 0 for clear, ~0 for set.
    int switch = (mask | 0x80000000 | lowestZero) +1 >> 31;
    return to & (switch | mask) | (switch & mask);
}
```

I was then able to shave off a couple of operations by reducing the expression:

```
int switch = -(~mask & 0x7fffffff & ~mask-1) >> 31;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I recommend you plug your function into [STOKE](https://github.com/StanfordPL/stoke). It is exactly the kind of function that it is good at optimizing. Is made to optimize C input, but it actually works in the x86 assembly domain, not the C domain (the output is assembly, not C code), but you can always try to translate the solution it finds back to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short one that produces good, branch-free code in practice:

```
int copy_bit(int mask, int to) {
  return (mask - 1 < 0) ? to & mask : to | mask;
}
```

Here's the [assembly generated on gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/H9PVN0):

```
copy_bit(int, int):
 lea    edx,[rdi-0x1]
 mov    eax,edi
 or     edi,esi
 and    eax,esi
 test   edx,edx
 cmovg  eax,edi
 ret
```

So only 6 instructions (excluding `ret`), including one `cmov`<sup>1</sup>, and 15 bytes of code.

Compare it to the assembly for the method shown in the question, which takes 15 instructions (no `cmov`), and 36 bytes of code:

```
copy_bit_orig(int, int):
 lea    eax,[rdi+0x1]
 mov    edx,edi
 not    edx
 and    edx,eax
 mov    eax,edi
 or     eax,0x80000000
 or     edx,eax
 mov    eax,edi
 add    edx,0x1
 shr    edx,0x1f
 or     eax,edx
 and    edi,edx
 and    esi,eax
 mov    eax,esi
 or     eax,edi
 ret
```

Keep in mind that your solution involves undefined behavior, since the operation `(mask + 1)` may overflow, which is undefined in `C` and `C++`. I needed to add the casts to my answer or else gcc would take advantage of this behavior to compile it to code that doesn't do what you'd expect.

---

<sup>1</sup> I call out `cmov` because on some architectures it is slower than simple ALU instructions, e.g., 2 cycles. On recent Intel CPUs it is fast, however.

Comment: Intersting, I did't know that conditional operator will compile without a jump. I'll have a look at how java handles it, as that was my primary interest; I didn't specify it as I judged this question more appropriate for low level specialists than java programmers who rarely think about such things. I'll probably accept it, and will certainly use it if I consider porting the library to c++

Comment: Indeed, even `if`/`else` causes often end up branch-free, if they involve a simple assignment to the same variable with different expressions. Compilers do a lot of magic in this area. On the other hand, whether it's actually a good idea to compile it to branch-free code almost always comes down to the probabilities of each side - if it is highly skewed, a branch is almost always better. Java doesn't have a problem generating branch free code either - you can check with `-XX:+PrintAssembly` and a small loop.

Comment: ... and of course in Java my comments above undefined behavior on overflow are moot. Furthermore, Java uses inlining heavily, so in cases where the mask is constant, it will generate great code (i.e, most of the code will disappear since it can be resolved at compile-time).